# How to connect to Postgresql database using Spring data reactive on Kubernetes?

Tags: spring-data, spring-webflux

I am able to connect to Postgresql database using Spring Data Reactive locally and using my H2 in-memory database for local testing.  However, when I deploy the app on a Kubernetes cluster with a Postgresql database cluster I keep getting the following error:

```
Caused by: io.r2dbc.postgresql.ExceptionFactory$PostgresqlAuthenticationFailure: pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host "10.244.2.232", user "myuser", database "account", no encryption
        at io.r2dbc.postgresql.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:75) ~[r2dbc-postgresql-0.8.10.RELEASE.jar!/:0.8.10.RELEASE]
        at io.r2dbc.postgresql.ExceptionFactory.handleErrorResponse(ExceptionFactory.java:111) ~[r2dbc-postgresql-0.8.10.RELEASE.jar!/:0.8.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandle.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.4.13.jar!/:3.4.13]
```

The following is my application.yml that contains the spring r2dbc url:

```
spring:
  r2dbc:
    url: r2dbc:postgresql://${POSTGRES_SERVICE}/${POSTGRES_DBNAME}
    username: ${POSTGRES_USERNAME}
    password: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
```

I do have another Springboot app that is not reactive which can connect to a another Postgresql cluster.
Is there a specific param that I need to send to my query string?

Comment: could you please check your pg_hba.conf ? `listen_addresses = '*'` check this config once.

Comment: yes the listen_address= '*' in postgresql.conf file.